# AWS cdk typescript shows error construct scope

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK TypeScript. I am trying to create an cognito userpool in cdk. But it is showing below warning at "this",

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
  Type 'RegionalCognitoCreation' is not assignable to type 'Construct'.
    Property 'onValidate' is protected but type 'Construct' is not a class derived from 'Construct'.ts(2345)
```

My code is like below,

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { UserPool } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito'

export class CognitoCreation extends cdk.Construct {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    new UserPool(this, 'myuserpool', {
        userPoolName: 'my-userpool',
    });    
  }
}
```

Please check[image] attachment.

My package.jso looks like below,

```
{
  "name": "******",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "regional-infrastructure": "bin/*****.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.53.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "10.17.5",
    "jest": "^25.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.3.1",
    "aws-cdk": "1.53.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cognito": "^1.54.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-elasticsearch": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions": "^1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.53.0",
    "@aws-cdk/custom-resources": "^1.53.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.716.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
}
```

I have run "npm install" and cognito and other modules are added in node modules. I tried changing "this" with "scope" but that didn't worked for me. My cdk version is `1.46.0 (build 63860b2)`

Comment: Can you please add more information: the CDK version used, the list of dependencies used (e.g. pasting package.json), did you run "npm install"? I had no issue when trying the user pool as described above.

Comment: Please find package.json and cdk version in above question. I did run "npm install".

Comment: Should your class be extending `cdk.Stack` and not `cdk.Construct`?

Comment: But I wanted to create this resource as part of same stack with other resource... Still I tries changing  cdk.Construct to cdk.Stack but that didn't make any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was some issue with my versions.
Making all versions of `aws-cdk` and `aws-*` the same solved the issue.
I did follow below steps:

- cd to your project path
- npx npm-check-updates -u
- npm install
- restart your IDE

Answer (score 4):

You've discovered a solution already, so I'm just posting this for posterity. The issue seems to come up a lot; I've dealt with it a number of times and it can be quite frustrating. The general advice is to delete node_modules, and re-install, making sure everything has matched versions. Be careful also if using a global install of the CDK and then calling it in the package.json. In that case you either need to remove the local install or run `npx` before the `cdk` command.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7280